# How to install Open Broadcaster Software (OBS) on Ubuntu 15.10 :/

Tags: apt, ffmpeg

I'm having a problem while installing OBS on Ubuntu 15.10 - I see that's no one ever faced this problem before on all the Ubuntu versions (14.04 , 13.10 , 15.04) and I have tried all those.

And please notice, I'm on OpenVZ virtualization.

So I want to broadcast to Facebook using OBS but while installing is:

libfdk-aac0 0.1.1 is required while the official FFMPEG PPA installs newer version.

I tried a lot of methods to force this error (dpkg , aptitue , apt-get install -f) but no benefit.

And it's the time to ask you guys.

Please help! thanks :)

Comment: Please if there's no benefit to do that . give me alternative to OBS which is good :)

Answer (score 4):

To install OBS on Ubuntu 15.10, simply run these two commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

It should automatically resolve and install the right dependencies.

Comment: I really don't know what's the difference +1
Now I get "Failed to initalize video" when trying to launch :(

Comment: @protld This is a problem with OBS and not Ubuntu. See [this thread](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/cant-start-obs-failed-to-initialize-video-unspecified-error.18925/).